# $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}} = ? $

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

This popped up when I was thinking about

$$(-1)^{\frac {p}{q}}$$

where $ p $ and $q$ are integers such that 
 $\gcd (p,q) = 1$

If  $p$ is even :

$(-1)^{\frac {p}{q}} = +1$

If $q$ is even :

$(-1)^{\frac {p}{q}}$ = a complex power with base $i $

If both $p$ and $q$ are odd :

$(-1)^{\frac {p}{q}} = -1$

$\sqrt2 $ cannot be written in the form $\frac {p}{q} $. So I was wondering whether there is a way to find the answer. My guess is that we will never know because we will never get to know the complete decimal expansion of $\sqrt2$.

Comment: is this $-(1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ or $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: @zz20 Latter one.

Comment: You could use the polar form of a complex number to deduce the coordinates of the complex number in question.

Comment: This power has infinitely many values forming a dense subset on the unit circle. The multi-valued nature of complex powers has been discussed many times here.

Comment: In the real numbers the expression $(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}$ is undefined; in the complex numbers it is “multivalued”.

Comment: You can get close to the result if you understood that $(-1)^x$ were a continuous function over $\mathbb{C}$, but that only works if you know how to define $(-1)^x$ in a way better than your definitions.

Comment: Even the case $(-1)^{p/q}$ is not as simple as you say.  It has $q$ different complex values.

Answer (score 3):

Using Euler's formula:

$-1=\exp(\ln(-1))=\exp(\ln(1)+i\arg(-1))=\exp(0+i(2k+1)\pi) =\exp(i(2k+1)\pi)$

for $k\in \Bbb{Z}$

Thus:

$(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}=\exp(i(2k+1)\pi\sqrt{2})=\cos((2k+1)\sqrt{2}\pi)+i\sin((2k+1)\sqrt{2}\pi)$

Answer (score 1):

You can write it as $$e^{\sqrt{2}\ln(i^2)}$$ now $\ln(i^2)=\ln(1)+i\arg(i^2)=0+i(2k+1)\pi$ thats it. You can continue now. Log of complex number is $log(z)=log(|z|)+arg(z)$

Comment: I think that the OP might've needed more help with the calculations, in fact, I don't even know if the OP knows about Euler's formula.

Comment: @Simple art Yes. I have not yet studied about them.

Comment: What exactly do you want?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I am assuming that the OP does not know what $arg(z)$ means and anything to do with Euler's formula, or even DeMoivre's formula.

Comment: @SimpleArt I think that most of the students would learn about arguments while learning about the complex numbers even if it is at basic level :/

Comment: @brainst I personally never did... :/  But maybe that's just me, or maybe the OP is really new to this stuff.  ${}$ -shrugs

Comment: @brainst I have not yet studied them. We have not even started complex numbers at school actually.

Comment: @SimpleArt ohh... ok , i guess my bad

Answer (score 1):

If you draw the unit circle, labeling the y-axis as complex and the x-axis as real, then $(-1)^{\sqrt2}$ has an angle of $\theta=180\sqrt2\approx254$ degrees and absolute value of $1$,

[image]

*not drawn to scale*

If you know trigonometry, the Cartesian coordinate of that spot is given as $(-1)^{\sqrt2}=\cos(254)+i\sin(254)$.

If you are interested in the actual reasoning behind this result, I would recommend looking up DeMoivre's formula, or proving DeMoivre's formula by calculating $(1+i)^n$ for $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and writing the distance from $0$ and the angle measures.  Then apply what you discovered about DeMoivre's formula on your problem.