# Why this hypergeometric function equals a complex number

Tags: hypergeometric-function

According to the following [Wolfram alpha calculator link](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=HypergeometricPFQ%5B%7Bpi%2F4%7D%2C%7B%7D%2C2%5D), this hypergeomtric function is a complex number$${}_1F_0(\pi/4;2)=(-1)^{\pi/4}=-0.78121\ldots-i×0.62425\ldots$$

I dont get it. I know that raising (-1) to a real power can give a complex number, what i dont get is how adding an infinite amount of real numbers equals a complex number. How?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1889795/1-raised-to-the-pi), why $(-1)^{\pi/4}$ is not a real number. And indeed, [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) need not be real.

Comment: I checked your Wolfram Alpha link, and it shows ${}_1F_0(\pi/4,2)$ is an infinite series of real numbers ... times $(-2)^{-\pi/4}$, which is certainly not real.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  i know how raising -1 to a real power can give complex numbers. What i dont get is how adding an infinite amount of real numbers equals a complex number.

Comment: Robert, of course a real sequence cannot converge to a non-real number because the real numbers are a closed subset of the complex numbers. But your series is not a real sequence.

Comment: There's a typo: the answer given by WA is $(-1)^{-\pi/4}$, not $(-1)^{\pi/4}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde What do you mean by "its not a real sequence"? It can be expressed as an infinite sum of real numbers.

Comment: I exactly mean what Hans says in his answer. It is **not** obtained by summing up only real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius of convergence of the power series is $1$, so the value at $z=2$ isn't obtained by summing a series of real numbers, but instead by **analytic continuation**. In [this case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#The_series_1F0), it's
$$
{}_1 F_0(a;;z) = (1-z)^{-a}
.
$$
According to the [Wolfram documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html): “For $p=q+1$, HypergeometricPFQ[alist,blist,z] has a branch cut discontinuity in the complex plane running from $1$ to $\infty$.”

Comment: Thank you for your time.